# TSQL: Creating a duplicate table and modifying values in the column properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a master table that I wish to keep as it is. I want to duplicate this table then find a specific record with a where clause and set a column value to `null`. I then want to reinsert it into the duplicated table without anything getting modified in the master table.

Right now these are the steps that I have taken, however, for some reason the changes propagate all the way to the master table:

1. ```
   select * into Table_Duplicate from Table_Master
   ```
2. ```
   create view vw_Filtered as 
   select Col1, null as Col2 from Table_Master where Col1 = 'Condition'
   ```
3. ```
   update
   set Table_Duplicate.Col2 = vw_Filtered.Col2
   inner join vw_Filtered 
   on Table_Duplicate.Col1 = vw_Filtered.Col1
   ```

Once Statement `3)` has been executed, when I do:

```sql
select * from Table_Master where Col1 = 'Condition'
```

I get the modified value in `Col2` but I want to get the value before updating it.

Please do let me know if there are any other way to achieve this.

Comment: [`output deleted.Col2 into ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Since your view always returns a NULL for Col2, your Table_Duplicate.Col2 will be set to NULL. When you say "I want to get the value before updating it." what do you mean?

Comment: By that I mean right now after statement three has been executed, table_duplicate.Col2 is set to zero and for some reason tablmaster.Col2 is also set to zero which i dont want to do. Say in tablemaster column 2 has a value 3.14159 i want to retain this value through any update set commands. Only tableDuplicate should be modified with the update set commands

Comment: [Updatable Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#updatable-views). You  created a new _table_ and a _view_. And the syntax for your `update` statement doesn't look right. You have an `inner join` between what sources? Are you actually updating the view and, therefore, the base table under it?

Comment: So view col1 is a unique list that is also found in table_duplicate col1. So the update is supposed to update the existing table_duplicate records with the records founds in the view

Comment: Why do you need the view? Why not just update the duplicate table directly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-complicating this.

I wont pretend I know why you need to do this in the first place, but if I had to do such a thing I would probably do it like this:

```
SELECT Col1, 
       IIF(Col1 = 'Condition', null, Col2) As Col2 
       [,Coln]  
INTO Table_Duplicate 
FROM Table_Master
```

Then you get all the process in a single select into statement.

Comment: Indeed. What you (seem) to want to achieve is a copy of the master table, with an extra column. If that's true, the above snippet is the best way.